# Import string from CSV to DateProperty in App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime

I'm trying to read a CSV file with a date format "06/01/05" (month/date/year) into a **DateProperty** (not DateTimeProperty) in App Engine (Python).  Here's what I currently have:

```
for row in mycsvfiledata:
    obj = MyObject()
    datetemp = row[1]
    cohorttemp = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetemp, "%m/%d/%y")
    obj.cohort_date.month = cohorttemp.month
    obj.cohort_date.day = cohorttemp.day
    obj.cohort_date.year = cohorttemp.year
```

and I get the error:
    [... omitted ...]
    obj.cohort_date.month = cohorttemp.month
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'month'

I've also tried:

```
obj.cohort_date = datetime.date.strptime(datetemp, "%m/%d/%y")
```

(but strptime only seems to generate a datetime object, not a date object)

```
obj.cohort_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetemp, "%m/%d/%y")
```

(but "cohort_date" is a DateProperty in App Engine, and I get "BadValueError: Property cohort_date must be a date, not a datetime" when I try that)

It all works fine if I just make "cohort_date" a DateTimeProperty, but I don't want that (for various reasons).  I'd appreciate any guidance on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime` instances have a `date()` method that returns the corresponding `date` instance, so:

```
obj.cohort_date = datetime.strptime(datetemp, "%m/%d/%y").date()
```